# Android, action bar / tabs problems

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

OK, so I've built a part of my app outside my main project (just in case anything went wrong) which works fine, then I added it to my main project. Both apps are compiled with 4.2 (I believe), but with my main project it just seems like it is still compiled with pre 4.0, I've attached a couple of screen shots, one with the app from were i built it and the other when I added it to my main project,

Both app are targeting 4.2, both have a min SDK of 8, [image: built outside project]

[image: after adding to main project]

Comment: What do you have selected in project properties -> android settings? Do both have 4.2 Android (17) selected? And what about application styles and themes?

Comment: thanks yes it was a theme problem... im still new!